# Scene builder has a problem with rendering JFXTextField component from JFoenix library

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix

I'm trying to add JFXTextField component to my scene by dragging the component, but it doesn't work (it always comes back). When I double click the component, it gets added to the list, but then my scene in scene builder will change to: "Content of this document cannot be displayed". If I would save it, I wouldn't be able to open it again, like it cannot interpret it's fxml tag. I already tried jdk 16, jdk 11 with scene builder 16 and 8 but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Problem in scene builder version 16.0.0 (but I didn't find the cause)
Install version 15.0.0 which works normally.
Download version 15 here:

https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/thanks/?dl=https://download2.gluonhq.com/scenebuilder/15.0.0/install/windows/SceneBuilder-15.0.0.msi

Comment: What an incredibly valuable answer. I've been hunting this link for 4 hours straight. Had a huge problem with Scene Builder java version (for instance, you can check it on Help > About Scene Builder). I needed java version 16 or lower, although could only find Oracle and Gluon versions, both incompatible with my project jars. This version is the one that I needed. This is the only link you can find referring to Scene Builder with java 17- builds. Thank you a lot.